# InnoSetup: How to select which component file to install from the Pascal script?

Tags: file, inno-setup, option-type

I need to install the one of 2 pre-built libraries with InnoSetup installer. They both have the same name, but their source is different.

The pascal script of InnoSetup should select which one of them will be installed without asking the user (basing on some registry keys only). So, I want to hide the "Select Components" page and implement something like that

```
[Files]
Source:"Main.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source:"Option1\Lib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: Option1 
Source:"Option2\Lib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: Option2
```

There should be either Option1 or Option2 selected from the script.

How can I do that? Maybe I don't need to use Components keyword at all and there is some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `Check:` parameter function to determine which to install.
You can then use `Check: InstallComponent1();` and `Check: Not InstallComponent1();` on each value.

Comment: Thanks! Strange how I missed this option in InnoSetup Help